# mysql service doesn't restart properly

Tags: mysql, apparmor

I install mysql server (version: 5.5.54) on ubuntu 14.04.
I have a script who optimize every day the DB and after that it restart mysql service.

today, i noted that mysql server doesn't properly restarted , when i connected to mysql i have this error.

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

in syslog i find these messages:

```
Mar 24 01:20:01 dbs kernel: [35113.530913] init: mysql main process ended, respawning
Mar 24 01:20:01 dbs kernel: [35113.549509] audit_printk_skb: 36 callbacks suppressed
Mar 24 01:20:01 dbs kernel: [35113.549514] audit: type=1400 audit(1490314801.743:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/sbin/mysqld" pid=21133 comm="apparmor_parser"
Mar 24 01:20:01 dbs kernel: [35113.568126] audit: type=1400 audit(1490314801.763:25): apparmor="DENIED" operation="mknod" profile="/usr/sbin/mysqld" name="/run/mysqld/mysqld.err" pid=21145 comm="mysqld" requested_mask="c" denied_mask="c" fsuid=105 ouid=105
```

mysql apparmor file

```
# vim:syntax=apparmor
# Last Modified: Tue Jun 19 17:37:30 2007
#include <tunables/global>

/usr/sbin/mysqld {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  #include <abstractions/nameservice>
  #include <abstractions/user-tmp>
  #include <abstractions/mysql>
  #include <abstractions/winbind>

  capability dac_override,
  capability sys_resource,
  capability setgid,
  capability setuid,

  network tcp,

  /etc/hosts.allow r,
  /etc/hosts.deny r,

  /etc/mysql/*.pem r,
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/ r,
  /etc/mysql/conf.d/* r,
  /etc/mysql/*.cnf r,
  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ r,
  /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/*.so* mr,
  /usr/sbin/mysqld mr,
  /usr/share/mysql/** r,
  /var/log/mysql.log rw,
  /var/log/mysql.err rw,
  /var/lib/mysql/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql/** rwk,
  /var/lib/mysql-files/ r,
  /var/lib/mysql-files/** rwk,
  /var/log/mysql/ r,
  /var/log/mysql/* rw,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid rw,
  /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,
  /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid rw,
  /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock w,

  /sys/devices/system/cpu/ r,

  # Site-specific additions and overrides. See local/README for details.
  #include <local/usr.sbin.mysqld>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by updating apparmor profiles.
Try this:

```
 apt install apparmor-profiles
```

Apparmor is restarted, I was able to start the DB normaly:

```
 sudo service mysql start
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
(source: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/unable-to-install-snap-from-store-or-locally/4629/15)

First remove apparmor and snapd (in my case the error was related to snapd, I don't think you have to remove it in your case)

```
sudo apt-get purge apparmor
sudo apt-get purge apparmor-profiles
sudo apt-get purge apparmor-utils
sudo apt-get remove snapd snapd-confine
```

Now Install back them all (again, you may not need to install snapd):

```
sudo apt-get install apparmor-utils
sudo apt install apparmor-profiles apparmor-profiles-extra vim-addon-manager
sudo apt install snapd snapd-login-service snap-confine
```